# Winning pitcher when tied

Tags: baseball, pitching

I have read the rules and threads but I am still unclear about this situation

The home team starting pitcher leaves the game after 6 innings leading 3-2. The relief pitcher comes in at the 7th. The visiting team ties the game. At the bottom of the 9th, the home team scores and wins.

Who is the winning pitcher? I say the relief pitcher and my son says the  starting pitcher, since the visitors never went ahead.

What is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Note it's the pitcher that records the last out of the 9th in this case, which is not necessarily the same pitcher who came in to start the 7th, that gets the win.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct (at least for MLB). Quoting from the [MLB rulebook, Rule 9.17 "Winning and Losing Pitcher"](https://img.mlbstatic.com/mlb-images/image/upload/mlb/wqn5ah4c3qtivwx3jatm.pdf):

> Rule 9.17(a) Comment: Whenever the score is tied, the game
> becomes a new contest insofar as the winning pitcher is concerned.

For other leagues, you would have to refer to the rulebook for that league but just about everybody copies MLB anyway.